# Como pasar un fichero a vector java

Tags: javascript, java, array, archivo

Hola tengo que hacer un trabajo y he de pasar el fichero que me dan a un vector, para despues manipular y poder ordenar los datos. Alguna idea, nose muy bien por donde empezar.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]; por favor haz el [tour] y lee [ask]. Tu pregunta tal cual como está terminará cerrada por múltiples razones. Debes demostrar que ya intentaste hacer algo, adjuntando un [repro]

Answer (score 0):

El fichero se encuentra en scv ? si es asi lo unico que deberias es abrir el fichero aplicar

```
const datos=fichero.split("aqui deberias colocar el caracter que separa cada dato")
```

automaticamente datos contendra el fichero separado en forma de un arreglo